# Can I have a inner shadow on both sides?

Tags: css

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 0px #BDD4DE;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 0px #BDD4DE;
box-shadow: inset 3px 0px #BDD4DE;
```

That puts an inner shadow on the left side. Is it possible to have an inner shadow on both sides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`box-shadow` accepts multiple values, so simply repeat your values with a `-3px` offset:

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 0px #BDD4DE, inset -3px 0px #BDD4DE;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 0px #BDD4DE, inset -3px 0px #BDD4DE;
box-shadow: inset 3px 0px #BDD4DE, inset -3px 0px #BDD4DE;
```

But those look more like borders than shadows. Perhaps you should use borders instead, and maybe with `box-sizing: border-box` in case you can't subtract from width or padding:

```
border-left: 3px solid #BDD4DE;
border-right: 3px solid #BDD4DE;
```

Comment: See also: [Can CSS3 box-shadow:inset do only one or two sides? like border-top?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917412/can-css3-box-shadowinset-do-only-one-or-two-sides-like-border-top) (using borders is more applicable here since you don't blur the shadows at all)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like this

```
box-shadow:0px 0px 5px Grey
```

The first and secod value is the offset (use no offset) and the third value is the blur value