# Box-Shadow Only on Left and Right

Tags: css

I am attempting to create an inset box-shadow on an element that only has the shadow on the left and right. I cannot get it to work.

Here is the box-shadow I tried:

```
 box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
```

I will add another one for the right side. The problem is this setting also shows the shadow slightly on the top and bottom and I cannot get it to not show and still show a shadow on the left side. Is this possible?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/C2LYF/)

Comment: Did you check near around `div`s or `elements` properties? Share the `jsfiddle` link.

Comment: I guess this is how **box** shadow means; maybe you can use `::before` pseudo element to drop the shadow instead.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997032/how-to-get-box-shadow-on-left-right-sides-only

Comment: @Lynda How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/C2LYF/1/ ? Notice that I changed your shadow color to `black` to better demonstrate, as the screen I'm using right now is crappy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a negative value on [spread-radius (4th value)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) to shrink the shadow. This can hide the unwanted top and bottom shadow.

```css
box-shadow: inset 25px 0px 25px -25px rgba(0,0,0,0.45), inset -25px 0px 25px -25px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5arLY/1/).

Comment: Note that this still creates a shadow along the top and bottom of the container.