# Add a box-shadow to a bootstrap site

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I would like to add a box-shadow to my site that uses bootstrap. I have applied a box-shadow to the body-content:

```
.body-content {
    background-color: white; 
    box-shadow:0 0 25px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.60);
}
```

However, I would also need the shadow on the nav-bar, because currently it looks like this:

Is there a standard solution for this? I have not found anything but hacks.

EDIT: Sorry for not being able to provide a fiddle..

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `.navbar` and the `.body-content` inside a div, apply box-shadow to parent div.

```css
.shadow-container {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.60);
}
.body-content {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.60);
  padding: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar {
  margin: 0 !important; /* Avoid !important, added here for priority in snippet */
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="shadow-container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img alt="Brand" src="...">
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="body-content">
      Rest of the content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Manoj. I don't want there to be space between navbar and content, the border on the navbar should only be on the left and right. It should look like one single box

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997032/how-to-get-box-shadow-on-left-right-sides-only

Comment: Also, the space between those elements is in the snippet only, it should not appear on your site.

Comment: I have edited the code and removed the spacing.

Comment: Thomas, Hamish's solution in your linked post uses fixed width which I cannot use.

Comment: Manoj, if I put a shadow-container around navbar and body-content, then it is stretched from the very left to the very right, so left and right shadow are not visible..

Comment: Can you post your current code? I am not sure about the problem unless I look into it. BTW Two people have asked to close this question because you have not posted the demo.

Comment: I've voted to close the question myself now... I will try and create a fiddle later. :o( thanks for your help anyways!