# How to make shadow 100% width under div

Tags: html, css, shadow

I made a fixed header div to my site and added a shadow under it but it doesn't fit my browser (100% width) ??

here is my css:

```css
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

#head{
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   background-color: #5B86E1;
  
   box-shadow: 0 10px 17px -5px #000000;
   position: fixed;
}

#content{
   width: 900px;
   padding-top: 60px;
   min-height: 100px;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="head">
 </div>
 
 <div id="content">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screen capture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most waterproof solution: make your element *longer*   (either with the `width` or `padding` property) than the viewport, and set negative margins (note: the margins are only really required to make this work with non-fixed elements). Your new `#head` css:

```
#head {
   width: 110%;
   margin: 0px -5%;
   height: 60px;
   top: 0;
   background-color: #5B86E1;
   box-shadow: 0 10px 17px 0px #000000;
   position: fixed;
}
```

As other answers have mentioned: it is advised to set the border-radius spread property to a non-negative value. Or you could use [separate box-shadows for each side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997032/how-to-get-box-shadow-on-left-right-sides-only).

Comment: Thanks Tyblitz, 
This is a very interesting solution. Bernhard's solution is good too ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You have a negative spread radius; for it to be full width you want this:

```
box-shadow: 0 10px 17px 0px #000000;
```

Demo:

```css
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

#head{
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   background-color: #5B86E1;
  
   box-shadow: 0 10px 17px 0px #000000;
   position: fixed;
   
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}

#content{
   width: 900px;
   padding-top: 60px;
   min-height: 100px;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="head">
 </div>
 
 <div id="content">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the fixed element a position using `left` `top` ``right```

```
header{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:60px;

    background-color:#00f;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 17px #000;
}
```

Added a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hpdymvqg/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is beause you have a negative value for your `box-shadow`. Changing it to the following fixes the issue:

```
box-shadow: 0 10px 17px 0px #000000;
```

Tested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b46gafrz/)

Comment: nope. you realize you test did not fix anything, right? ;)