# how to get box-shadow only left and right sides only using css

Tags: html, css

Here is code i have tried but box shadow

```css
div {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<div>abc</div>
```

what i need is this, [image] ,  It is possible using background image but what i want to do this using css.

here is original image : [image]

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get box-shadow on left & right sides only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997032/how-to-get-box-shadow-on-left-right-sides-only)

Comment: here i have attached image what i wanted finally i get an idea how to do this box shadow as per above answer.

Comment: Your image is just 23px??

Comment: @Prasanga Do you really think anyone can understand anything from this small image? Btw good to hear that the link was helpful.

Comment: yes and see there is gray color horizontal line in the image. that is what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

@Prasanga Please find following code as per your requirement.

```css
div {
    box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.

Comment: @Prasanga Welcome, Please raise a vote on answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this ---

```css
    div {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: yellow;
     box-shadow:0px 15px 0px 0px white,0px -15px 0px 0px white, 5px 0px 8px #444,-5px 0px 8px #444;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple here :

```css
div{
        background: white;
        box-shadow: -10px 0 8px -8px black, 10px 0 8px -8px black;
    }
```

```css
 <div>abc</div>
```