# box shadow to left and right doesn't work

Tags: css, box-shadow

I want to make box-shadow to the left and right sides,however there is alway a shadow in the top of the box,I have checked my code many times.

```css
#box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-top-color: #e99f2e;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 20px 2px #7f7e7f, -2px 0 20px 2px #7f7e7f;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get box-shadow on left & right sides only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997032/how-to-get-box-shadow-on-left-right-sides-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First understand the `syntax` of `box-shadow` and then it get's easy to apply box-shadow at any side as you have planned your design,

```
syntax -
box-shadow : offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color
```

```css
#box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 2px -2px #7f7e7f, 10px 0 2px -2px #7f7e7f;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  background:#cff;
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome @W.J :-)

Comment: however it won't work at my data :-2px 0 20px -2px #7f7e7f  once the blur-radius become 20px,all side will have the shadow .Could help me with that?

Comment: @W.J Check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c3eow8me/ you need to adjust offest-x, offset-y and spread-radius

Comment: Thank you so much !Last question.How can I control the length of shadow?

Comment: @W.J Increase length, you need to do that using blur-radius and spread-radius, keep on changing until you get planned result. https://jsfiddle.net/c3eow8me/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack actually.

You can achieve this by adding an "empty" top and bottom shadow.

```
box-shadow: 0 9px 0px 0px white, 0 -9px 0px 0px white, 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(30, 53, 125, 0.9), -12px 0 15px -4px rgba(30, 53, 125, 0.9);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect if you set the `spread` to the negative of `blur` parameter. For the left box shadow, set `position` to negative `blur` and the right box shadow, `position` to positive `blur`. I used `20px` in this demo:

```css
#box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-top-color: #e99f2e;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 20px 0px 20px -20px #7f7e7f, -20px 0px 20px -20px #7f7e7f;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Check out [this CSS Box-shadow generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Box-shadow_generator) to explore further.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: however it won't work at my data :-2px 0 20px -2px #7f7e7f once the blur-radius become 20px,all side will have the shadow .Could help me with that?

Comment: first and last value should be -20px, not -2px

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is as good as the other answers, but this is an alternative approach using absolute positioned pseudo elements with shadows.

```css
.lr-shadow {
  background:#fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top-color: #e99f2e;
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.lr-shadow:before, .lr-shadow:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #7f7e7f;
  content:" ";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  height:90%;
  z-index:-1;
}
.lr-shadow:before {
  left:5px;
}
.lr-shadow:after {
  right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lr-shadow"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply!Looks prefect!