# Making box-shadow not override its adjacent box

Tags: css, vue.js, css-selectors

I have an issue. I have a couple of cards in my application. Now we want to give those cards a box-shadow but also merge them to a big card instead of having them separately. So 2 cards will look like 1, since they will be connected on one of their sides.

Every one of those cards are modules coming from the CMS and it is impossible to put them in a wrapper together. Otherwise I would create a parent div and give the box-shadow to this div.

Thus, the result is the following:

[image]

I would create a hack that targets the n-th element of the cards and remove its box-shadow from one side. But that is also impossible as the number of cards that are connected can be more than 2 depending on the step of the checkout.

Thus, the question that rises is: When u have adjacent cards, can you somehow remove the box-shadow from their connecting points with maybe simple CSS? I have been struggling with it the whole day.

Comment: You can use :first-child and :last-child selectors to make the box shadow in top of the first and bottom of the last card

Comment: This is tricky indeed, since box-shadow will always spread on all sides... Could this SOF question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997032/how-to-get-box-shadow-on-left-right-sides-only

Comment: @Adri thanks for your answer mate. As I said, the number of cards is N. Thus, not possible

Comment: @Kapcash went through them, I don't think so

Comment: You can apply a "side only" box-shadow to all elements and a 3 sided shadow on the first-child and last-child elements. But as said, 2 or 3 sided box-shadow are tricky and usually does not render well.

Comment: Do these cards have a wrapper after all? Do they cover 100% of parent's height?