# How to get box-shadow to appear on ngGrid rows?

Tags: css, ng-grid

In this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MtSzEk?p=preview) you can see I've tried to make an inset drop-shadow appear in the viewport area of the grid. It is visible in the space where there are no rows, but none where the rows are. I don't quite understand what about the rows is blocking it.

Below are my styles:

```
.gridStyle .ngViewport
{
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.gridStyle .ngFooterPanel, .gridStyle .ngTopPanel 
{
    box-shadow:0 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

Is there a way to get the box-shadow to be visible even when rows are present in the viewport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see the box-shadow because the the row elements are on TOP of the ngViewport element that has the shadow. If you make the ngViewport container wider than the rows, you'll see the shadow appear at the edges.

Comment: I see. Is there no way to create the appearance that the rows are shadowed by their container?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `cellClass` to define inset box-shadows for the appropriate side(s) of the cells (see [Can CSS3 box-shadow:inset do only one or two sides? like border-top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917412/can-css3-box-shadowinset-do-only-one-or-two-sides-like-border-top))