# Vertical line with shadow

Tags: html, css

I want to create a vertical line shadow over the whole page like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsJCE.png. I've tried box-shadow but that then I still have a shadow at the top and I want it only on the right side like on the image.

I've tried it with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Box Shadow Test</title>
    <style>
    body,
html {
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:#000;
background:#52667B;
}
    wrapper {
        width:750px;
margin:0 auto;
background:#99c;
    }


    #main {
        padding-left: 50px;
float:left;
width:500px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 0px 5px -2px #000 ;
}
#sidebar {
float:left;
width:250px;

}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar" class="navigation">

    <ul>
        <li><a href='home'>Nieuws</a></li>
        <li><a href='events'>Duiken</a></li>
        <li><a href='places'>Duikplaatsen</a></li>
        <li><a href='reports'>Duikverslagen</a></li>
        <li><a href='forum'>Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href='gallery'>Galerij</a></li>
        <li><a href='faq'>FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href='contact'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

        </div>
        <div id="main">
            Lorem ipsum aute commodo cupidatat veniam occaecat esse culpa exercitation dolore magna commodo enim eiusmod laboris est dolor laboris velit sint voluptate id cillum nisi quis aliqua ut labore consectetur Duis nisi occaecat do et cupidatat in aute labore nulla consequat dolore dolor consectetur cupidatat fugiat eiusmod tempor anim eiusmod dolor proident ex aute sunt Excepteur cupidatat fugiat nostrud irure id laboris ad enim nulla deserunt quis eu ullamco consectetur tempor nostrud magna quis ut ex minim id cupidatat amet culpa amet nisi Duis Duis irure irure ullamco est dolor culpa esse id in ut reprehenderit in esse pariatur in nostrud fugiat labore ut irure do in consectetur incididunt ullamco sint do occaecat dolor Ut pariatur non sint ut in incididunt id Duis aute nulla et eu ullamco in tempor non nisi reprehenderit sit reprehenderit et tempor officia sunt pariatur aliquip in pariatur labore veniam ad adipisicing velit aliqua aliqua cillum esse Duis pariatur eiusmod sed consectetur in cillum laborum dolor enim laborum qui velit pariatur adipisicing id aute cupidatat cupidatat quis anim tempor ad labore ad sunt minim laborum exercitation labore sunt quis nulla consequat Duis deserunt deserunt eiusmod aliqua sed in qui occaecat do velit reprehenderit dolor dolor cillum veniam dolor consectetur est commodo deserunt eu amet velit velit commodo est reprehenderit aute. 
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But as you can see on this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/01My9.png you still have some shadow on the bottom side.

Anyone have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: try this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115427/box-shadow-only-on-one-side

Comment: Thanks for the link, bu as you can see in my code I used his box-shadow line and started from there. If you remove his border you can see you still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use `box-shadow` instead of  `-webkit-box-shadow`. And than, just play with the values 'til you get the perfect shadow.

I tried this:

> box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px -4px #000 ;

Then add `position:absolute;` and `top:0` and `bottom:0;` to `#main`

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/magq5/1/