# Shadow only to right

Tags: css

Following is the jsfiddle in which I am trying to drop shadow with blur effect only to the right but the shadow is spreading to every side. Please kindly let me know how to modify this fiddle to drop shadow only to rigt thanks,

http://jsfiddle.net/6UFX7/8193/

```
.myDiv {
     margin: 10px;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0px 5px 0px #888 ;
 }
```

Comment: note the fiddle will work on chrome only..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Box-shadow only on one side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115427/box-shadow-only-on-one-side) - solution is remarkably similar to your fiddle.

Comment: @Tanner I checked that question but the solution was not displaying shadow only to one side

Comment: this jsfiddle from the solution has a right shadow only: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/6UFX7/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/6UFX7/8194/)

**CSS:**

```
.myDiv
{
  margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px -2px #888 ; /*Chrome*/
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px -2px #888 ; /*Firefox*/
    -o-box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px -2px #888 ;  /*Opera*/
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px -2px #888 ;
}
```

Use the `shadow-spread` property(fourth) to make the user think that the shadow is only on one side and yes also increase the amount of the `horizontal offset` property(first) to make the trick work.

Answer (score 1):

```
.myDiv
{
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 20px 0px 5px -2px #888 ;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 0px 5px -2px #888 ;
}
```

20px position R/L
0px  position T/B
5px  spread(blur)
-2px "size"