# Add box-shadow to table column (top to bottom)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*I have this simple table where if I click on a column - I need to make the whole chosen column ( from top to buttom ) as selected.*

I don't have a problem with colors or html  , but I do have a problem with the `box-shadow` css property.

This is how it should look :

[image]

Please notice `"right-shadow"` and `"left-shadow"` (bottom- I don't care)

But When I tried to make it ( [**JSBIN SAMPLE**](http://jsbin.com/manacigi/5/edit)) via JQ :

`$("#tblPlan td:nth-child(2)").addClass('shadow')`

Where :

```
.shadow
{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px  black;
}
```

It applies it to all borders  ( *As it should obviously* ) (including inside ):

[image]

**Question**

How can I achieve to a solution where **only** left and right ( bottom I don't care) - will be shadowed ?

[**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/manacigi/5/edit)

Comment: p.s. I can't change table to div's.

Comment: eeewwww.... I just thought of a solution ( ugly one) - z-index div transparent which will be on top of the column and will have the shadow...eeewww

Comment: I initially recommended using `<col>` and `<colgroup>`, but it looks like it doesn't support `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsbin.com/manacigi/22/edit) to use a inset-box-shadow with :before and :after elements, as shown in [this great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17323375/2690156).

I think it's the best looking css-only solution for your problem, most other hacks have very round shadows, which looks odd.

Comment: +1 though there's no need for jquery. Here's an updated CSS-only version: http://jsbin.com/zazasezuki/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

**Your css class:**

```
.shadow
{
    box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px -5px black, -10px 0px 10px -5px black;
}
```

Giving a negative value in the fourth paramenter (-5px) you indicate the shadow spread.
You can see something similar in this answer: [How can I add a box-shadow on one side of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115427/box-shadow-only-on-one-side)

Answer (score 0):

You may use pseudo element and relative/absolute position to draw shadow and bg colors: http://jsbin.com/manacigi/17/edit

Updated css:

```
        #tblPlan
        {

        table-layout: fixed;
         width:100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border:solid 1px lightgrey;
          position:relative;
          overflow:hidden;

        }

        #tblPlan tr:first-child td+td
        {
        white-space: nowrap;
        }



        #tblPlan td:first-child
        {
             padding-left:20px;
        }
        #tblPlan td
        {border:solid 1px lightgrey;

        padding:15px 5px 15px 5px;
        }

        #tblPlan td+ td
        { 
        text-align: center;
        }




        .shadow
        {
          box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 100px #5FCBE5;
          position:relative;

        }
.shadow:before,
.shadow:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:1px;
  box-shadow:-2px 0 2px;
}
.shadow:before {
    left:0;
}
.shadow:after {
  right:0;
    box-shadow:2px 0 2px;
}
```